# Cocoa Touch Static Library - Link with Standard Frameworks

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, static-libraries

I have created a cocoa touch static that uses standard apple frameworks like MediaPlayer.framework and CoreData.framework. When I link my main project against this static library it throws errors because that library requires those frameworks.

My question: Is there a way to set the Static Library to link against those frameworks so I don't need to add them to my main project? I tried to add the frameworks to the static library's "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase, but the main project still throws a fit.

There is probably some sort of Build Setting flag I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way to achieve this. You have to link your main project against the frameworks that are used by the library.

Comment: Although I am apt to believing this from my experience, the GData static library seems to somehow accomplish this. There are libraries packaged in their static library which must be included when compiled because my main project did not require me to re add them when adding GData and linking against it. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: After further investigation, it seems the GDataFramework target is including these frameworks in the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase but the GDataTouchStaticLib does not include these libraries. Considering the framework has multiple targets, for iOS and Mac OS, they must be able to do this at the Framework level but not the cocoa static library level. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I don't know about MacOS frameworks in general, but GData contains all the files in one project, even though they say *The library incorporates other Google libraries with the GTM prefix* what they do is they basically add the source files to the GData project. If you take a look at the framework target, it only links to **Security** and **SystemConfiguration**, there are no submodules linked neither to the framework, nor to the static library target.